# Vscode ng serve compiling again and again

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular8, angular-cli-v8

On windows 10 ng serve keeps compiling again and again without saving any changes. Even when I switch between two files in vscode it recompiles.

But when I run the same angular project on a macOS it behaves properly.

Comment: Is auto save enabled?

Comment: No. Even I thought it might be that but no autosave is not enabled.

Comment: I'd reinstall vs code ... I doubt it has anything to do with windows/os, most likely a plugin is failing.

Comment: It's a new setup. I recently switched from macOS to windows 10.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13099) check this url and i think you have to update the angular packages

Comment: Not useful. Already tried that.

Comment: Can it be a case that my vscode plugins are doing something when I open a angular code?

Comment: @PritamKadam Looks like Auto formatter or some auto plugins are enabled in your vs code. Have you found any formatting changes or any spacing changes when you open new file or tab ??

Comment: @AkhilNaidu No auto formatter was never enabled. Autosave was also never enabled. Now just a few minutes back I have enabled "Format on save" feature of vscode. Also, I have removed 5 vscode extensions. I'll need to check for a few days how is the behavior after removing a few extensions. I'll update after 2-3 days.

Comment: An Angular application or a Native-script application ? i remember having the same issue with a Native-script app ?

Comment: What is your Angular CLI version? What is your NodeJS version? Did you try to compile your project with different NodeJS major version?

Comment: @kuncevic.dev 
Angular CLI: 9.0.1
node =>12.16.0
npm => 6.13.4

Comment: Removed couple of vscode extensions still getting the same issue

Comment: @PritamKadam were you ever able to figure this issue out? i'm having the same problem with VS Code and Windows 10 in Angular 8 and 9 apps. A teammate using the same apps on mac does not.